# Como hacer que un campo acepte nulos con laravel 8?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8, null, migration

Como le puedo hacer para que cuando haga una migración y este por ejemplo:

`$table->string('Email');`

Como puedo hacer que el campo acepte nulos en la base de datos?

Answer (score 2):

$table->string('Email')->nullable();